# Why is $1+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{j-1}\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\dots k}{3\cdot4\cdot\dots k+2}=3-\frac{2}{j+1}$

Tags: summation

> Why is $1+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{j-1}\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\dots k}{3\cdot4\cdot\dots k+2}=3-\frac{2}{j+1}$

If one has the result it is not difficult to verify it by induction, but how can I solve it without induction ?

Comment: $$\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\dots k}{3\cdot4\cdot\dots k+2}=\frac{2}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac2{k+1}-\frac2{k+2}$$

Comment: This can also be solved in one line using [difference calculus](http://homepages.gac.edu/~sskulrat/Courses/2013S-256/notes/1d.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have : 
$$
\begin{split}
\require{cancel}
\dfrac{1\cdot2\cdot\bcancel{3\cdot4\cdot5\cdots k}}{\bcancel{3\cdot4\cdot5\cdots k}\cdot k+1\cdot k+2}&=\dfrac{1\cdot2}{k+1\cdot k+2}\\&=\dfrac{2}{k+1}-\dfrac{2}{k+2}
\end{split}
$$

So the summation $S_j=\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\dfrac{1\cdot2\cdots k}{3\cdot4\cdots k+2}$ is a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) and is equal to:

$$
\begin{split}
S_j&=\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\left(\dfrac{2}{k+1}-\dfrac{2}{k+2}\right)
\\&=2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{j+1}\right)
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac r{r+2}=\dfrac{1\cdot2}{(n+1)(n+2)}=2\cdot\dfrac{n+2-(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=?$$

See [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\begin{align}
1+\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdots k}{3\cdot 4\cdot5\cdots k+2}&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\frac{k!}{(k+2)!/2}\\\\
&=1+2\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\\\
&=1+2\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)\\\\
&=1+2\left(1-\frac{1}{j+1}\right)\\\\
&=3-\frac{2}{j+1}
\end{align}$$